# Wireless Debugging on QuickTime Player? (Xcode9)

Tags: ios, xcode, quicktime, xcode9

Has anyone been able to connect wirelessly to **QuickTime Player**? I'm able to debug wirelessly using Xcode 9, but when I try to connect to QT, the device won't appear on the list...

I've already gone to devices and made sure "Connect via Network" is checked. This works fine if I use the lighting cable.

This is what Apple says on the Xcode 9 page:

> ### Cut the Cord
>
> Choose any of your iOS or tvOS devices on the local network to install, run, and debug your apps – without a USB cord plugged into your Mac. Simply click the ‘Connect via Network’ checkbox the first time you use a new iOS device, and that device will be available over the network from that point forward. Wireless development also works in other apps, including Instruments, Accessibility Inspector, **Quicktime Player**, and Console.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see my iPhone in QuickTime too, despite wireless debugging in Xcode 9 works fine. I guess we might need a new QuickTime version, probably the one which goes with High Sierra. Has anyone tried wireless screen recoding with it?